# Angular 2 Ahead-of-Tme compiler: about CSS

Tags: angular, deployment

`Angular 2 rc 6` written in `typescript 2`

Until now, I've used Just-in-Time compilation to compile and run my app in the browser. My components link to their stylesheets like so:

```
@Component({
    ...
    styleUrls:['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

At that location however, there is no `.css` file, but an `.scss` that gets compiled to CSS and placed next to `app.component.js` during a gulp build task.  So at the time the app runs in the browser, the `.css` is present as expected.

Now, I'm learning how to use Ahead-of-Time compilation. When i run `ngc`, I get the error:

> Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: C:/path/to/app.component.css

This is expected of course since there is no CSS stylesheet there. How do you guys deal with this? Do you not use SASS any longer?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: My `styleUrls` still refer to `.css`, and my styles are still written in a `.scss`. To get around the problem, I have a build step that compiles each `.scss` to a `.css` saved at the location where the Angular compiler expects to find it. Lately I've been using the [Angular Seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) as the basis for my app. It comes with a few pre-configured build steps and a bit of instructions on [how to use SASS styles.](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Working-with-SASS)

Comment: I'm using the seed and reference the .css file as well so it sounds like we have the same setup. In your build step, where did you compile the css to? The same directory as the .scss file or within the AoT folder?

Comment: @tctc91 The seed handles that transparently if you set it up to use SASS. I didn't have to meddle with it. In `gulpfile.ts` file, the AoT build is a task named `build.prod.exp`. A step within that task -- `build.html_css` -- will convert your SASS files into CSS and place the results into a temporary folder (`/dist/tmp`) where the AoT compiler will be looking for them.